# AWS Route53 not routing the web traffic to failover server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Im testing Route53 for failover between two servers on same zone for a domain `xyz.com` with TTL 60 seconds only. I have also setup the healthchecks for primary server only to monitor the URL `http://<primaryIP>:80`.
The primary and secondary servers both have nginx running with security group open for port 80. when i stop the nginx on primary server the `A record` is switched to the backup server's IP when i used dig to find A record but I cannot browse the domain `xyz.com` or `ping xyz.com`

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue on your machine.

Comment: ...specifically, many/most/all browsers seem to cache existing lookups until you close all browser windows. Verify this? Or try a different browser on the same machine?

Comment: i had already cleared browser history/cache

Comment: Did you also verify @Michael-sqlbot's suggestion (different browser on the same machine)? It really does sound like a cached lookup on the browser (the OS NS cache should obey your TTL). Remember this is your DNS cache-- try `chrome://net-internals/#dns` on Chrome or this answer for [Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063496/firefox-invalidate-dns-cache)